Mechanism to Determine Appropriate Stack Exchange Site
I see a lot of moderators migrating questions from one site to another pretty often, but tonight I had a question which doesn't neatly fit into any in the list.
Is there a mechanism, or even a dedicated Stack Exchange site available to assist those with questions which don't seem to fit any of the site topics or involve nuances which cross the boundaries of multiple site topics to post those questions to the most appropriate site or possibly even trigger the consideration of a new Stack Exchange site to focus on a novel discipline or subject?

I presume you mean a site (not server). The short answer is there is not an "everything is allowed" site, although if you have something in mind, you can ask for help finding the appropriate site by asking here on MSE. I'm having trouble finding the link, but somewhere there's a post that explains in detail why having an everything site wouldn't work.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/401178/135565 maybe?

Are you sure it is a lot? And when you say moderators do you mean the users with a diamond or does that also include users with flag/close privileges that pick "belongs on other site" as close reason?

If you're cunning, you might be able to refashion the question to be on topic on  [worldbuilding.se].

I once did a migration from super user to writing

Very much related.

Migrations are not as common as you think, and don't necessarily need moderators. There's some sentiment that migrations are outmoded and we don't need them, and as a moderator, I try to only migrate exceptional questions that're in the wrong place.
In theory, you can ask a question about where a question fits in here on meta. That said, we're not expecting perfect topicality — we expect questions to fit what's on topic and be practically answerable. There is overlap between various sites, and often a migration means it's a good  enough question that someone decided it's better to rehome it.
If it's something outside our current scope completely, in theory the area 51 process of creating a new site should cover it, but you need significant effort to do it, and currently the site and processes are somewhat inoperable.
